# Use page-object，how to locate the strong element

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I find the page - the object of the website，But I couldn‘t find method of strong element..Who can tell me whether there is a strong method..or whether can use with watir-wevdriver method：
for example：

```
link :note_new do |page|
page.note_list_element.strong(:index,0).link_element(:index, 0)
```

end

thank you very much!

Comment: What is exactly the problem here? Do you want to access `strong` element using page-object or watir-webdriver API?

Comment: I want to use page-object to locate a link element in strong element.How should I handle..

Answer (score 3):

For strong elements, you can use the page object's generic element methods.

**Creating elements in a page object**

To declare a strong element in your page object use [`element`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors#element-instance_method):

```
element(:a_name, :strong, :index => 0)
```

This will generate 'a_name', 'a_name_element', and 'a_name?' methods

**Accessing strong elements within another element**

If you want to access a strong element from another page object element, there is another [`element`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/ElementLocators#element-instance_method) method:

```
element(:tag_as_symbol)
```

For your example, you would want:

```
page.note_list_element.element(:strong).link_element
```

Note that the `:index => 0` is implicit (ie you do not need to specifically include it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to locate the  dom element. There is strong method in watir-webdriver.
`ruby
@browser.strong(:how, what)`

Hope this would be help.